# Starting new activity from onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I want to start another Activity from post execute and pass some arguments to it. But it force closes the app. This is my `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (result != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+captionStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Article.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("url", "Hello"); //Your id
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
                context.startActivity(intent);
                // context.finish();*/
            }
        });
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

My manifest declaration

```
<activity android:name=".com.tdodemo.tdo.Article" />
```

LogCat

```
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546): Process: com.tdodemo.tdo, PID: 15546
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1146)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1133)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:328)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at com.tdodemo.tdo.ImageLoadTask$1.onClick(ImageLoadTask.java:82)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4562)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18918)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
09-04 10:53:30.759: E/AndroidRuntime(15546):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why is  imageView.setOnClickListener in onPostExe....?

Comment: Post your Logcat Errors

Comment: In doInBackground() I am am loading image from server and in onpostExecute() I am seting it to an ImageView. On clicking this image I want to start another Activity.

Comment: @Manasi post the error in your post to let us debug the problem

Comment: The error says it all: you need to add a flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Edit: or add `Context` variable to your `AsyncTask` and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add flag **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Article.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("url", "Hello"); //Your id
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
Intent intent_name = new Intent();
intent_name.setClass(getApplicationContext(),Article.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("url", "Hello"); //Your id
intent_name.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent_name);
```

OR

Since one of the argument of your AsyncTask is the activity you can directly use

```
Intent intent_name = new Intent(activity, Article.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("url", "Hello"); //Your id
intent_name.putExtras(b);
activity.startActivity();
```

hope this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with your Activity name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR ACTIIVITY NAME.this , Article.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

by seeing your logcat it is saying about required flag.Try it by adding that flag in your intent

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tis code, tis is working for me

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyAsyncTaskActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
            Context().startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, move this

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(context, ""+captionStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Article.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("url", "Hello"); //Your id
            intent.putExtras(b); //Put your id to your next Intent
            context.startActivity(intent);
            // context.finish();*/
        }
    });`
```

Outside of the onPostExecute, onto your main activity after you call your asyncTask class is called. onPostExecute save the image to the drawable directory, change your imageView to
        `imageView.setImageBitmap(res.drawable.Image);`

Comment: But my current class is an asyncTask

Comment: I forgot about that sorry mate, try my new solution @Manasi